# Cannot disable default activity animation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation

I have been trying to replace the default activity transition animation but without any success.

Ihave defined my own entry and exit animations and in the callback where the new activity is launched I have the following code:

```
public void goFetchCallback(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecipiesActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.entryanim,R.anim.exitanim);
}
```

Unofrtunately this does not do the work and I do not know why.

I am running this on a Motorola Xoom with ICS.

I have also tried to disable the default animation by using a custom style as below:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>      
</style>
```

and assigning this to the applicatioin in Manifest.xml but again without any success.

Can somebody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in the code that was disabling the animation. The problem was with the animation itself. In fact, it was almost the same as the default animation of Xoom and therefore the confusion.

For completeness I am posting the code for disabling the animation and also the entry and exit animations. They achieve a right to left animation together with some fading.

When calling the acitvity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, RecipiesActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(intent);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.entryanim,R.anim.exitanim);
```

The entryanim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="100%"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"/>
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" 
        android:duration="1000"/>
</set>
```

and the exitanim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">

    <alpha 
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"/>
</set>
```